# echart code error in angular 9 but can work in angular 7

Tags: angular, echarts

I am using angular 9 and ngx-echarts (4.2.2) to build the charts.

```
this.pieEchart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('pieEchart'));
this.pieOption['legend']['data'] = ['good','bad'];
this.pieOption['series'][0]['data'] = [
    {value:322, name:'good'},
    {value:333, name:'bad'},
];
this.pieEchart.setOption(this.pieOption);
```

The code above used to work fine in angular 7, but got a running error in angular 9

core.js:5845 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at Object.getAttribute (model.js:494)
    at getInstanceByDom (echarts.js:1976)
    at Object.init (echarts.js:1899)
    at ChartComponent.setPieChart (chart.component.ts:379)
    at ChartComponent.ngOnInit (chart.component.ts:45)
    at callHook (core.js:3909)
    at callHooks (core.js:3873)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3814)
    at refreshView (core.js:11723)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13070)

anyone encounter this problem before ?

Comment: Have you had any success with solving this problem?